# Regex for flexible key/value pairs

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm looking for something a bit more specific than the generic solutions and am stuck. The regex is intended for us in logstash' JRuby which I believe is Ruby 1.9.3 compliant.

http://regexr.com/3fas9 - sample regex sandbox

```
  [\w\d]+\s*=\s*.+?(?=$|[ ,]+[\w\d]+\s*=)
```

Having trouble ensuring just one word is captured when not quoted and capturing the last key/value pair. Thanks for the start mudasobwa.

Sample input

```
  c.k.a.e.s.impl.TestImpl - EventServiceImpl.something - event k1 = 4060936, k2 = 563486, kdod = 5882fe842bf9a9afd9611012 ssfk4=1,k5="two words" sk6=one word k7="int,comma" extra value
```

Expected matches output

```
k1 = 4060936
k2= 563486
kdod = 5882fe842bf9a9afd9611012
ssfk4=1
k5=two words
sk6=one
k7=int,comma
```

Bonus challenge output if the spaces are the equals can be massaged by the regex. If not I can post process and it's fine.

```
k1=4060936
k2=563486
kdod=5882fe842bf9a9afd9611012
ssfk4=1
k5=two words
sk6=one
k7=int,comma
```

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Would this really have been a much better question if I had included my naive key=value matching that failed the hard parts anyway? Wow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`([\w\d]+)\s*=\s*(?:"([^"]+?)"|([\w\d]+))`](http://regexr.com/3faue)

**Flags**: Ignore-Whitespace, Global

**Key**: Group 1, **Value**: Group 2 or Group 3